# Orbeon - get the uploaded file while form send

Tags: xml, web-services, orbeon, xforms

When user completed form (on Form Runner) and push "send" dates are sent to web service and web service save as xml (or to the database). I have a problem with files uploaded by users. In sample xml:

```
                <?xml version="1.0" ...>
                    <section-1>
                        <control-1>user1 test</control-1>
                        <control-3>user1 test</control-3>
                         <control-4 filename="cbsidlm-cbsi134-Quick_HTML_Color_Picker-ORG-10400979.exe" mediatype="application/octet-stream" size="894600">/fr/service/persistence/crud/UFWoD/Test1/data/e619cbc6a5f015c17bb29d79c232115e5bbb107f/21c63e421691466124b54fbbba687f48f401eb59.bin</control-4>                           
                    </section-1>
                </form>
```

How can i get this file and save it (it`s different server with web service, Orbeon has own separated serwer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the XML snippet you quote, your service receives a URL, which has the form (actual ids in the URL are longer, and I shortened them below to make this more readable):

```
/fr/service/persistence/crud/UFWoD/Test1/data/e619/21c6.bin
```

Your service can retrieve the file by making a call to the Orbeon Forms persistence API, which means making an HTTP GET to:

```
http://server.com/orbeon/fr/service/persistence/crud/UFWoD/Test1/data/e619/21c6.bin
```

In the above URL, replace `http://server.com/orbeon` by the actual URL on which your Orbeon Forms is deployed. Also, note that since version 4.0, access to services is protected by default. For more on this, see [Authorization of pages and services](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/page-flow-controller/authorization).

Comment: Hi, Can I know if you were able to use the mentioned URL
and save the file in your local disk. How did you fix the authorization 
settings? Thank you.

Comment: @NomeshDeSilva Are saying that you have an issue retrieving the file using the URL in the XML you receive?